# redis sessions keep pilling up

Tags: node.js, session, redis

Since it's my first question here, I'll try to be as specific as possible.
I'm using express 4 and connect-redis module to store my sessions. For some reason when I start the node app, I notice 2 sessions on redis. This will go on and the sessions on redis will keep pilling up. How is this possible? I mean without even using my browser?

As I understand sessions are bound to the cookie that is created on the browser. Then where all the other redis sessions come from? Since the environment is local, there should be only one session on redis right?

**Update**
Here's my server.js code:

```
var http     = require( 'http' )
, compress        = require( 'compression' )
, methodOverride  = require( 'method-override' )
, cookieParser    = require( 'cookie-parser' )
, bodyParser      = require( 'body-parser' )
, session         = require( 'express-session' )
, express         = require( 'express' )
, passport        = require( 'passport' )
, redis           = require( 'redis' )
, RedisStore      = require( 'connect-redis' )( session );


var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');  

var config       = require( './configs' );

var port = process.env.PORT || config.env_port;

app.use(compress());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'1mb'}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));

/**
* REDIS SESSION STORE
*/

var ses = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.host);
ses.auth(config.redis.pass);

var session_routes = '(?!\/api)(*)'

app.use(session_routes, session({
  secret  : 'secret',
  cookie  : { maxAge: 7200000 }, //2 hours
  rolling : true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  rolling: true,  
  store   : new RedisStore({ client: ses })

}));

app.use( session_routes, passport.initialize() );
app.use( session_routes, passport.session() );



app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(" Listening on " + port);  
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to post some commented code relevant to the issue? It would help us giving some context to your question in order to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with code.